# Pagination for CSqlDataProvider in CGridView

Tags: php, yii, pagination

I wanna display the retrieved data i.e CSqlDataProvider in CGridView through Pagination..
  and I retrieved data from table through CSqlDataProvider and shown in CGridView 
 but the problem is at Pagination part..
Firstly look at my Controller code..

```
        $count = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT COUNT(familyid) FROM (' . $sql2 . ') as count_alias')->queryScalar();

        $rawData = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql2);

        $dataProviderRegSum = new CSqlDataProvider($rawData, array(
                'keyField' => 'familyid',
//              'pagination'=>false,
                /* 'pagination' => array(
                        'pageSize' => Yii::app()->user->getState( 'pageSize', Yii::app()->params[ 'defaultPageSize' ] ),PaymentTxnDate
                ), */
                'pagination'=>array('pageSize'=>20),
            'totalItemCount' => $count,
                'sort'=>array(
                        //'defaultOrder' => 'CreatedDate desc',
                        'defaultOrder' => 'PaymentTxnDate asc',
                        'attributes'=>array(
                                'RegistrationID'=>array(
                                        'asc'=>'familyid',
                                        'desc'=>'familyid DESC',
                                ),
                                'FirstName'=>array(
                                        'asc'=>'firstname',
                                        'desc'=>'firstname DESC',
                                ),
                                'LastName'=>array(
                                        'asc'=>'lastname',
                                        'desc'=>'lastname DESC',
                                ),
                                'CreatedDate'=>array(
                                        'asc'=>'CreatedDate',
                                        'desc'=>'CreatedDate DESC',
                                ),
                                'EmailedDate'=>array(
                                        'asc'=>'EamiledDate',
                                        'desc'=>'EamiledDate DESC',
                                ),



                        ),),

        ));
```

and my view is as

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
            'id'=>'family-record-grid',
            'dataProvider'=>$arr[1],
            'enableSorting' => false,

            //'enablePagination'=>false,

            'itemsCssClass'=>'tabchin',

            'columns'=>
            array(),
));
```

here $sql2 is my query....

$arr[1] is dataprovider that has sent from controller to view as array...

I have `totlaItemCount` value
       and `pageSize` is `20`

All is right but in the output the first 20 records are displaying its ok
but pagelinks i.e pagenumbers for pagination is not displaying at the bottom..

its been two days stuck for this error ..still didnt get solution 
please help me anyone thanks for reading the stuff...

help needed..

Comment: How many items are returned by the query?

Comment: 298 records are returned by query

Comment: y ,is there anything wrong in code...

Comment: @topher what happend